# Can't copy props to model data and render it in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having this problem that looks a lot like a bug to me and I can't figure out how to solve it.

I created a generic list component and I tell it what child component it should insert in each item and what are the data it should pass to the child component. I'm passing everything as props along with the list (array) itself.

The problem is that I can't mutate the list props. So I try to copy it to model attribute. Otherwise I get this error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders.....

And I can't just make it work in any of the lifecycle events. When I save the file and the hot-reloading reloads the page, the list is there, rendered, full of items. When I press F5 to manually reload the page, it is no more. Everything seems to be alright with code though

So in the parent component I'm doing this:

```
<List ref="link_list"
:list="this.foo.links" //this is array
:child="'LinkFormItem'" //this is the name of the child component
:section_name="'Links'"
:defaults="{content: '', type: 'facebook'}" />
```

In the List component I get this:

**Template**

```
<li class="" v-for="item in datalist">
    <component :is="child" :item="item" ></component>
    <button v-on:click='remove(index++)' type="button" name="button" class='red button postfix small'>Remove</button>
</li>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
import Child1 from './Child1'
import Child2 from './Child2'

export default {
    name: 'search',
    props: ['child', 'list', 'defaults','section_name'], //it is received as 'list'
    components: {
        Child1, Child2
    },
    data () {
        return {
            index: 0,
            datalist: [] //i'm trying to copy 'list' to 'datalist'
        }
    },
    beforeMount: function () {
        // i'm copying it
        for(var k in this.list){
            this.datalist.push(this.list[k])
        }
    },
    methods: {
        //and here I should change it the way I want
        add: function () {
            this.datalist.push(this.defaults)
        },
        getList () {
            return this.datalist;
        },
        remove(index){
            var datalist = [];
            for(var k in this.datalist){
                if(k != index) datalist.push(this.datalist[k]);
            }

            this.datalist = datalist;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I don't see any problems with my Script. What is going on??

**@edit**
Ok, some `console.log` later I found out what the problem seems to be. The HTTP Request is really taking much longer than the mounting of the component to happen. But when it happens, it is not triggering the update in the list component. Nothing is re-rendered and the list is empty.

**Workaround**

well I realised the problem was related to propagation. I made a few changes in the code to asure the parent component was updating and changing the model value. but the child component (the list component) was not receiving it.

then I gave up trying to understand why and did the following:

1- used the `ref` in the child component to force an update in the child component with `$forceUpdate` and then I was assigning the props to the model in the `beforeUpdate` event. It was causing an error: an re-rendering loop. The update caused a new update and so on. We could just use a flag to stop it.

2- Instead I just called a child method directly:

```
this.$refs.link_list.updateList(data.links);
```

I hate this approach because I think it's way too explicit. But it did the job. Then in the child component a new method:

```
updateList(list){
    this.datalist = list;
}
```

3- The other possibility that passed through my mind was emitting an event. But I didn't try, too complicated

Comment: Are you sure that there is data in `this.list`, inside the `beforeMount` function?

Comment: It should have, shouldnt it? The weirdest of the things is that when the hot reloading reloads the component, the list is alright! At a certain point i even thought i made it work :/

Comment: Well if the list is populated thru ajax, the `beforeMount` function could potentially be called before the ajax is done. It makes sense that the list works after a hot reload, because `beforeMount` is called again, and the ajax has finished. Just do a `console.log` and see what's there.

Comment: Also i don't see how your child components could work. You've locally registered the child components with keys `Child1` and `Child2`, but you're passing `'LinkFormItem'` as the component name. That shouldn't work, unless you've globally registered the components somewhere else..

Comment: A fiddle would do wonders here.

Comment: Victor, Bert - I've deleted my post as Bert is 100% correct. I forked his CodePen to test, adding a List component to mirror the question scenario.

Comment: Victor I notice you're using a self closing tag on <List>. See this (it's a little old),  https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036.

Comment: Hey eric. That was a very good point and it is populated after an http request. About the child component, i renamed everything but forgot to rename the reference name in parent component

Comment: Guys I just updated my question. See 'edit' in the ending. @RichardMatsen I did as you suggested. nothing changed though

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do like as follows

```
data () {
        return {
            index: 0,
            datalist: this.list // to copy props to internal component data 
        }
    },
```

Once you done about you need to apply data manipulation opertions on new `this.datalist` , not on `this.list`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mutate the original list array you can do this:

```
data () {
     return {
        index: 0,
        datalist: Object.assign({}, this.list) 
     }
}
```

I think this will help you